# Error: 404 NOT FOUND

Tags: c#, angularjs, asp.net-mvc

**Services.js:**

```
app.service("CRUDservices", function ($http) {

this.selectEmployees = function () {
    return $http.get("/api/Empdet/SelectEmployees");
};

this.selectEmployee = function (id) {
    return $http.get("/api/Empdet/SelectEmployee/" + id);
};

this.addEmployee = function (Empdet) {
    var request = $http(
    {
        method: "post",
        url: "/api/Empdet/AddEmployee",
        data: Empdet
    });
    return request;
};
this.updateEmployee = function (id, Empdet) {
    var request = $http(
    {
        method: "put",
        url: "/api/Empdet/UpdateEmployee/" + id,
        data: Empdet
    });
    return request;
};
this.deleteEmployee = function (id) {
    var request = $http(
    {
        method: "delete",
        url: "/api/Empdet/DeleteEmployee/" + id,
        data: Empdet
    });
    return request;
};
});
```

**EmpdetController.cs:**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Http;
using System.Web.Http.Description;
using Task1.Models;

namespace Task1.Api.Controllers
{
public class EmpdetController : ApiController
{
    private EmployeeEntities db = new EmployeeEntities();

   [HttpGet]
    public HttpResponseMessage SelectEmployees(Empdet empdet)
    {
        Collection<Empdet> Empdets =new Collection<Empdet>( db.Empdets.ToList());
        return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, Empdets);
    }

   [HttpGet]
   public HttpResponseMessage SelectEmployee(int? id)
   {
       var empdet = db.Empdets.Find(id);
       if (empdet == null)
       {
           return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotFound);
       }

       return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, empdet);
   }


    [HttpPut]
    public HttpResponseMessage UpdateEmployee(int id, Empdet empdet)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid && id == empdet.Id)
        {
            db.Entry(empdet).State = EntityState.Modified;

            try
            {
                db.SaveChanges();
            }
            catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException)
            {
                return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotFound);
            }

            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
        }
        else
        {
            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public HttpResponseMessage AddEmployee(Empdet empdet)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Empdets.Add(empdet);
            db.SaveChanges();

            HttpResponseMessage response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Created, empdet);
            response.Headers.Location = new Uri(Url.Link("DefaultApi", new { id = empdet.Id }));
            return response;
        }
        else
        {
            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }
    }

    [HttpDelete]
    public HttpResponseMessage DeleteEmployee(int id)
    {
        Empdet empdet = db.Empdets.Find(id);
        if (empdet == null)
        {
            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotFound);
        }

        db.Empdets.Remove(empdet);

        try
        {
            db.SaveChanges();
        }
        catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException)
        {
            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotFound);
        }

        return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, empdet);
    }

    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        db.Dispose();
        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }
}
}
```

**ShowempController.js:**

```
app.controller("ShowempController", function ($scope, $location, CRUDservices, SharedData) {

$scope.loadRecords = function () {
    //CRUDservices.selectEmployees().success(function (response) {
    //    $scope.Employees = response;
    //});
    console.log('init');

    var promiseGetEmpdet = CRUDservices.selectEmployees();

    promiseGetEmpdet.then(function (pl) {

        console.log(pl);
        $scope.Employees = pl.data
        console.log($scope.Employees);
    },
        function (errorpl) {
            $scope.error = 'failure loading employee', errorpl;
        });        
};

$scope.Addemp = function () {
    $location.path("/Addemp");
};
$scope.Editemp = function (Id) {
    ShareData.value = Id;
    $location.path("/Editemp");
};
$scope.Deleteemp = function (Id) {
    ShareData.value = Id;
    $location.path("/Deleteemp");
};
});
```

**Showemp.cshtml:**

```
<html  ng-app="ApplicationModule">
<body>
<div ng-controller="ShowempController" data-ng-init="loadRecords()">
<h2>List of Employees</h2>
<a ng-click="Addemp()">Add Employee </a>
<br />
<table border="1" class="mytable">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Id</th>
            <th>PhotoFile</th>
            <th>FirstName</th>
            <th>LastName</th>
            <th>Email</th>
            <th>Age</th>
            <th>PhotoText</th>
            <th></th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="Empdet in Employees">
            <td>{{Empdet.Id}}</td>
            <td>{{Empdet.PhotoFile}}</td>
            <td>{{Empdet.FirstName}}</td>
            <td>{{Empdet.LastName}}</td>
            <td>{{Empdet.Email}}</td>
            <td>{{Empdet.Age}}</td>
            <td>{{Empdet.PhotoText}}</td>
            <td><input type="button" value="Edit" ng- click="Editemp(Empdet.Id)" /></td>
            <td><input type="button" value="Delete" ng-click="Deleteemp(Empdet.Id)" /></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<div>{{error}}</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Whenever i try to execute this program it says error: 404 not found, its not hitting SelectEmployees in the Showempcontroller.js i have cleary mentioned in the Empdetcontroller.cs file for selecting all employees i use "SelectEmployees"  and for a single data retrieve i used "SelectEmployee and referring it by Id". But still its not hitting the file and not executing. Please Help!!!

Comment: return $http.get("/api/Empdet/SelectEmployees"); change to  return $http.get("/api/SelectEmployees") and check if it works

Comment: i see your controller `SelectEmployees` is parametrised but i see nothing passed from ajax call ? check on it .

Comment: Narrow down your problem and add only relvent code, Please just don't dump your entire code.

Comment: You can also use  **return $http.get("/api/Empdet")**

Comment: You should examine the http network traffic to see exactly what URL is being called. Switch on 'Developer' tools in your favourite browser or use an external package like Fiddler.

Comment: Are you using any config.js file also for $routeProvider??? If yes plz provide that also

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Solution 1**

You need to assign the  `[ActionName("Name")]` attribute for your *action*

Because *Web Api* only taking *get, post, put,delete* method name for the *get and post* reason

> if you change the *action* name, then you need set the *ActionName attribute*

Like

```
[ActionName("SelectEmployees")]
[HttpGet]
    public HttpResponseMessage SelectEmployees(Empdet empdet)
    {
        Collection<Empdet> Empdets =new Collection<Empdet>( db.Empdets.ToList());
        return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, Empdets);
    }
```

---

**Solution 2**

- And also please check the `Parameters`. You should be pass the correct parameter object and values to your controller actions .

---

**Solution 3**

verify your paths in your WebApi config file

Making your route url look like

```
 config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "DefaultApi",
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
            );
```

- And your url should be look like `$http.get("/api/Empdet/SelectEmployees")`

---

I hope you can solve it from my key answer :)

Comment: Thanks for the help and the problem is solved now but while i execute its loading the records from the database and storing it to scope but its not getting displayed

Comment: please ask the new problem via new question

Comment: I m binding the data correctly but its not displaying it for checking the route in use console.log but its carrying the data as object array but not displaying pls help.

Comment: Sure i will make a new question.

Comment: Show me you array object :(

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to give any action name as suggested above
You can also use return **$http.get("/api/Empdet")**